# jQuery: Display only matching characters in autocomplete dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, autocomplete

I'm making my own dropdown script in jQuery. Things are going well, but I'm running into a problem. Whenever I enter any characters into the text field, all elements in the array I am searching are displayed, instead of the elements that match what's in the textbox.

For example, if I regex search for "ra" against my array of:

```
var planes = [
    'Alara',
    'Fiora',
    'Innistrad',
    'Kamigawa',
    'Lorwyn',
    'Mirrodin',
    'Ravnica',
    'Shandalar',
    'Zendikar'
];
```

I should only see Ala**ra**, Fio**ra**, Innist**ra**d and **Ra**vnica in the autocomplete.

[Here's a Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/MogNfPSj2Pt0Oy886iKp)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare to -1, so it will only show if it is found. You are currently comparing to 1 instead, so it returns true for all items. Probably a typo. Good luck!

```
        else{
            //Grep used to search array but not alter the original.
            var results = $.grep(planes, function(item){
                return item.search(new RegExp(query, "i")) != *add a - here* 1;
            });
            console.log("Added " + query + " to cache.");
            cache[query] = results;
        }
```

Comment: Yup, that was it! The -1 is critical!